# ActiveRecord Rails 4.2 - Filter includes query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to improve some queries in my Rails 4.2 project. One query in particular, is done in an API Controller. The query is as follows (just as example):

```
@books = Book.includes(:pages).where( category_id: 1 )
```

This is producing the following SQL:

```
SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books".category_id = 1

SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."book_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

This is nice, it's behaving OK in the database side.

Then let's suppose that I need to filter the books based on a page attribute. The query would be something like this:

```
@books = Book.includes(:pages).where( category_id: 1, pages: { attr1: 'bar' } )
```

This is producing the following SQL:

```
SELECT "books".attr1, "books".attr2, "pages".attr1, "pages".attr2
FROM "books"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "pages" ON "books".id = "pages".book_id
WHERE "books".category_id = 1 AND "pages".attr1 = 'bar';
```

This is not necessarily bad. However I would like to have the following SQL instead:

```
SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books".category_id = 1

SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."book_id" IN (1, 2, 3) AND "pages".attr1 = 'bar'
```

You see, it's easier to create indexes for each separate query in the database.

Is there a way that I can achieve what I want?

Thanks.

PS: Please excuse any typo in the written code.

Comment: @books = Book.includes(:pages).where( category_id: 1).where(pages: { attr1: 'bar' } )

Comment: Something like `Page.includes(:books).where(book_id: [1,2,3]).where(attr1: 'bar')`?

Comment: If you have indexes on `books.category_id` and `pages.attr1`, they should both be used in the left outer join example. Take a look at `Book.includes(:pages).where( category_id: 1, pages: { attr1: 'bar' } ).explain` to get more information on how the query will be executed.

Comment: How do you receive the pages condition? Is it a static condition or it depends on outside params? For the static condition you may define a relation with condition.